# text substitution on version strings with GNU make

Tags: versioning, gnu-make

This question is specific to GNU make. Given a version string in makefile, say:

```
VER = 1.23.345.6
```

Is it possible to strip off trailing component(s) from the string? Let's say desired result is the first 2 components, that is (major.minor):

```
VERPREFIX = 1.23
```

Although it can be achieved with `$(shell)` using command line programs that supports regular expression (such as `sed` or `perl`), I'd wonder if native text filtering functions in GNU make can achieve same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# Create a variable $S containing a space
E :=
S := $E $E

# Get the first and second elements of a version string
VERPREFIX := $(subst $S,.,$(wordlist 1,2,$(subst .,$S,$(VER))))
```